# How to create Custom SonarQube plugin

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-plugin

I have a utility for which given a path of project repo, it will scan the repo to identify if test methods uses certain patterns. For example check if contract test methods have some string like - 'RxHttpClient'. Given path of cloned project, the utility works just fine and lists all methods using specific pattern.

The ask is to run this utility at PR level using SonarQube. Currently Sonar is integrated for my project, so I have been asked to create a custom rule/plugin which can be deployed to Sonar server. As I am new to SonarQube, having trouble getting started and what should be the approach.

any suggestions on this would be really helpful. I will share more details as required.